# Custom toolbar in Xamarin Cross-platform that work in all platform

Tags: xamarin.forms

Here I have posted image that exactly I want using Xamarin cross-platform that run on all android,windows and iOS.

Top and right side logout button image.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Something wrong with toolbar - `ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("name", "icon.png", () => { }));` ?

Comment: Thanks @YehorHromadskyi  its working now.